# Javascript how to chain promises that include ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I'm trying to construct a processing pipeline builder of sorts, where the user can define the order of operations. I need to use the resulting list of operations to determine the sequence in which functions are being chained together. Each internal function contains an `$.ajax()` call, and I need for that cal to complete before the next processing step begins. The processing steps must proceed synchronously, despite the internal components of each step being asynchronous.

It seems like `Promise` chaining would do exactly what I need, but I'm failing at adapting [the examples on this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) to my use case (see below for simplified pseudo-code of what I've tried to do). I can't figure out how to weave waiting for `runProcess_()` to finish before fulfilling the `Promise`.

Can anyone help?

```
var pipe_order = ['C', 'A', 'B']  // this is user-defined, order can change

function runProcessA() {
    var data = { "some_data": some_data }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/run_ProcessA',
        data: data,
        success: (response) => {
            // return message for pipeline functionality
            var pipe_step_response = 'ProcessA Step Complete.'
            return pipe_step_response;
        }
    });
}


////////////////
// FOR SAKE OF SIMPLICITY, assume runProcessB() & runProcessC()
// are mostly identical to runProcessA()
////////////////


function failureCallback(error) {
    console.error(`Error in process step: ${error}`);
}

function runPipeItem(process='end_of_pipe', index=0) {

    index += 1  // increment the index so there is not a 'Step 0'

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          
            if (process!=='end_of_pipe') {
                console.log('Pipeline beginning: Step ' + index);

                if (process==='correct') {
                    console.log('runProcessA: start')
                    var step_complete = runProcessA(process, true);
                } else if (process==='translate') {
                    console.log('runProcessB: start')
                    var step_complete = runProcessB(process, true);
                } else if (process==='summary') {
                    console.log('runProcessC: start')
                    var step_complete = runProcessC(process, true);
                }

                // record that the process is finished
                console.log(step_complete)
                console.log('Pipeline finished: Step ' + index);

                // reveal HTML element
                document.getElementById(`step-${index}-completed`).style.display = "block";

            }

          // The fulfillment value of the promise
          resolve(index);
        }, 200);
      });
}


function runPipeline(pipe_order) {
    var uploadStatus = checkUploadReady();
    if (typeof uploadStatus === "string") {
        alert(uploadStatus);
        return; // Stop the function execution
    } 

    // check status and send stop request if running
    const stopSignal = toggleRunStatus();
    if (stopSignal) {
        return; // Stop the function execution
    }

    // JSON container for anything that needs to be passed to Python function
    var data = {
        "pipe_order": pipe_order,
    }

    // iterating through pipe_order
    runPipeItem(pipe_order[0], 0)  // step 1
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 2
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 3
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 4
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 5
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 6
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 7
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 8
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 9
        .then((newIndex) => runPipeItem(pipe_order[newIndex], newIndex))  // step 10
        .then((newindex) => {
            console.log('Pipeline completed all steps.');
        })
        .catch(failureCallback);

}
```

Comment: `$.ajax({` -> `return $.ajax({` which will return a promise-like object suitable for chaining.

Comment: @VLAZ, this did not work for me, can you be more specific? or maybe provide corrections within a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: @magnawhale the main concern is for your function, runProcessA, to be any use for chaining you need to return the promise from it. That's what `return $.ajax(...` would accomplish. At that point, you can .then on it and do whatever once it is done, or even just await sequentially.

Comment: Next, however, you will need to make sure `resolve` within `runPipeItem` is only called once the promise returned from `runProcessA` has resolved. aka, `runProcessA(process, true).then(resolve)`

Comment: which, of course then makes your index handling not work... but... i'd just remove that bit all together. it was a hack anyway